# How to make my app to support multitasking

Tags: iphone, ipad, multitasking

i am developing an app for iphone and ipad with 4.0 as base SDK and 3.0 as target.
how to enable multitasking to this app.

thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I support Fast App Switching in an iPhone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087076/how-do-i-support-fast-app-switching-in-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1867-how-to-update-your-iphone-app-for-multitasking-with-ios-4/

Also duplicate question [how to do multitasking application in ios 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181314/how-to-do-multitasking-application-in-ios-4-0)

Comment: i added the 'application background mode' with item - App plays audio in my info.plist. because i am playing an audio . is there any thing  else to change.?

Comment: i deleted other than needed appdelegate methods, its worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To adopt Multi-Tasking in your app. apply the following points:

1. Support all orientation from the target's General section in settings.
2. In the General section too. remove the check next to `Requires full screen` if any.
3. Select storyboard, click the File Inspector icon in the right side bar. check the box next to `Use Size Classes`. Check out tutorials how to use size class to adjust your views according to the screen size assigned to your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you build an iOS app using a 4.x SDK, Apple's "multitasking" will be enabled by default, unless you explicitly add a plist key to prevent it.

But multitasking may not work properly unless you add support for it in the app's resign/become active, and/or app's suspend/resume delegates.

If you actually want to run code in the background, then your app needs to be of a few very specific types, or add support for running some code for a very limited amount of time, for which you probably want to read Apple's documentation.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
 //exit(0);
   }.......the audio is stopped but i want it to play in the background.when i click on app its playing again.

Comment: If you want to play audio in the background, then you need to add the background audio plist key (and obey a few other rules, as per Apple's documentation).